# Run the same line of code but incrementing the number. Swift, Php

Tags: php, ios, swift, alamofire

I want to run the same line of code but incrementing the number "prodottiNome_prodotto**0**" and forKey: ("nome_prodotto**0**") always.

```
let prodotti = jsonData.value(forKey: "prodotti") as! NSDictionary



let prodottiNome_prodotto0 = prodotti.value(forKey: "nome_prodotto0") as! String

self.defaultValues.set(prodottiNome_prodotto0, forKey: "nome_prodotto0")
```

nome_prodotto**0** refers to the result of a return in php ------------>

```
"prodotti":{"nome_prodotto0":"farina","nome_prodotto1":"dfd"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, your code might look like this:

```
let max = 50 //Or whatever limit you want to use

for i in 0...max {
  let key = "nome_prodotto" + String(i)
  //Use `if let` so you don't crash if a value is not a string
  //Don't use `value(forKey:)` on a dictionary. That's a KVO method
  if let value = prodotti[key] as? String {
    self.defaultValues.set(value, forKey: key)
  {
}
```